# When a timerfd (set in user space) expires, execute a piece of user-defined code in the Linux kernel

Tags: timer, linux-kernel

I have set a timerfd in the user space, when it expires, I would like the kernel to execute a piece of code I added.  Anyone can give me some suggestions?

Some ideas I have: accordding to the definition of *timerfd_setup* in file /fs/timerfd.c, the function *timerfd_tmrproc* is called. Can I add my codes inside the function *timerfd_tmrproc* ? My codes concern reset one self-defined variable (in sched_entity) as zero, so I also need to pass the tid of the thread to the function *timerfd_tmrproc*. Will it cause any risk to the system?

```
static int timerfd_setup(struct timerfd_ctx *ctx, int flags,
             const struct itimerspec *ktmr)
{
    enum hrtimer_mode htmode;
    ktime_t texp;
    int clockid = ctx->clockid;

    htmode = (flags & TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME) ?
        HRTIMER_MODE_ABS: HRTIMER_MODE_REL;

    texp = timespec_to_ktime(ktmr->it_value);
    ctx->expired = 0;
    ctx->ticks = 0;
    ctx->tintv = timespec_to_ktime(ktmr->it_interval);
    hrtimer_init(&ctx->tmr, clockid, htmode);
    ***hrtimer_set_expires(&ctx->tmr, texp);
    ctx->tmr.function = timerfd_tmrproc;***
    if (texp.tv64 != 0) {
        hrtimer_start(&ctx->tmr, texp, htmode);
        if (timerfd_canceled(ctx))
            return -ECANCELED;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need the timer to be a timerfd, and not a kernel timer?

Comment: I sense an xy question here; if you're both setting the timeout from userspace as well as want to run userspace code when it expires ... why are you not simply using a mechanism that's made for this (`sigitimer()` / `timer_create()` / `[u]alarm()` and the use of the signal handler comes to mind, if the code is "contained" enough), but if you insist on `timerfd_create()` then why not spawn a thread that just `poll()`s on the timer fd ... and runs the code you want when that returns ?

Comment: @CL. I am multi-threading several threads that are created through pthread. I want one thread behaves like a periodic thread. Thus, I use *timerfd* to create a timer before a loop, and add *read (info->timer_fd)* to wait until the end of one period. I learned that *timerfp* uses hrtimer in the kernel, and I hope when the timer expires, it allows to execute a piece of code that I have added in the kernel space. One doubt I have is that, is the timer created by *timerfp* is independent of the user space code? I hope so, but seems the next period only starts when the timer is read in user space.

Comment: @FrankH. Hi, I think there is a misunderstanding. Sorry for my expression. The idea is to set the timer in user space, but execute a piece of code in the kernel space when the timer expires. Ideally, I hope when the timer expires, it can (periodically) interrupt the user space activities and execute a small piece of code in the kernel space.

Comment: Why do you think that this thread needs to be in user space? And why can't that thread just tell your kernel code to execute something?

Comment: @CL I am proposing a scheduling algorithm and using a pthread-based testbench to assess its performance. My purpose is to reset one variable X (inside *sched_entity*) of a periodic thread at the end of each period. e.g. if a thread has a period of 1s, then, every second the variable X is reset to be 0. I have thought about using an extra high-priority thread to do this work. But it may bring too much overheads considering we have to managing N threads for N periodic thread under scheduling. Hopefully this can be done through the timerfp created in the userspace code of each periodic thread.

Comment: @CL. I hope to add and execute a piece of code after the timer expires. However, I am worrying the timer created through timerfp only start a new period when it is read in the userspace. In this case, the reset of variable X can not be done periodically.

Comment: Doing everything in the kernel would be much easier.

Comment: @CL I agree. I will try to create a kernel timer that restarts independently of the timerfd, while the two of them begin the first counting at the same time. A backup option is to create one thread for each periodic thread to do the resetting work.